# Rewrite rule with internal redirect not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I believe the solution I am looking for is quite simple but I have spent almost a day searching for it without success, so I surrender.

I would like to redirect all requests from `portail.domain.com` to the `portail-index.php` file, and all other requests (from my other subdomains) to the `index.php` file.

This is my `.htaccess` file :

```
# ROUTING portail SUBDOMAIN TO portail-index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portail.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^portail-index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /portail-index.php [NC,L,QSA]


# REROUTING EVERYTHING ELSE TO index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

And here are the log results when I try to access `portail.domain.com` :

```
 applying pattern '.*' to uri ''
 RewriteCond: input='portail.domain.com' pattern='^portail.*' => matched
 RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/app/preprod/' pattern='!-f' => matched
 RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/app/preprod/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
 RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='^/$' => matched
 rewrite '' -> '/portail-index.php'

 trying to replace prefix /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/ with /
 internal redirect with /portail-index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

 strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php -> index.php
 applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'

 RewriteCond: input='portail.domain.com' pattern='^portail.*' => matched
 RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 RewriteCond: input='/index.php' pattern='^portail-index.php$' => not-matched

 strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php -> index.php
 applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
 RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 pass through /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php
```

Now I perfectly understand that causing an `internal redirect` replays the battery of rewrite rules. **What I don't understand is why the second pass doesn't match the `portail.domain.com` rule again.**

I tried replacing the `L` flags by `END` flags, but to no avail. The result was exactly the same. I also tried several adaptations of those rewrite rules, but none of those attempts worked. I spent hours reading the Apache rewrite_mod documentation, so I believe I understand the module quite well, but can't get it to work properly in this case.

Any suggestion as to why it is not working, or even better : how to make this work, is most welcome.

**--- EDIT ---**

Many thanks for your help @Anubhava. Here are the logs I get after implementing you version of the `.htaccess` file :

```
strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/ -> 
applying pattern '^' to uri ''
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/' pattern='-d' => matched
pass through /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/
strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php' pattern='-f' => matched
pass through /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php
```

Does that leads you anywhere ?

**--- SECOND EDIT ---**

```
strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/ -> 
applying pattern '^' to uri ''
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/' pattern='-d' => matched
pass through /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/
strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
RewriteCond: input='/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php' pattern='-f' => matched
pass through /home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod/index.php
```

I really do not get why calling `portail.domain.com` doesn't lead to `portail-index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some redundant conditions. Have your rules like this:

```
# ROUTING portail SUBDOMAIN TO portail-index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portail\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.)?[^.]*$ portail-index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# REROUTING EVERYTHING ELSE TO index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^portail\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: He he, you again :) 
Could you explain to me quickly what happens after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` ? 

I'll implement your solution in the meantime

Comment: Damn... Your suggestion, as it is, doesn't work. It still brings `portail.domain.com` to the `index.php` file. I'll post the logs within my question above, so you can see what happens

Comment: Only those two lines go on top of the `.htaccess` file content I posted : `RewriteEngine on` and  `RewriteBase / `. The url I access is `portail.domain.com`

Comment: The `DocumentRoot` for `portail.domain.com` is `/home/ubuntu/domain/app/preprod`

Comment: Hmmm... It is getting weirder and weirder... (See second edit above)

Comment: I believe this has to do with `DirectoryIndex`. It was set to `index.php index.html` within the `VirtualHost <Directory>`. Removing it worsen the problem however, leading to look for `index.cgi`, then `index.pl` until reaching `index.php`. I'll keep on digging this way

Comment: OK. So now, `whatever.domain.com` is resolved to `index.php`, while `portail.domain.com` is resolved to `portail-index.php`, which is a big step forward. However, all dependencies (js and css files) are also resolved to `portail-index.php` on `portail.domain.com`, as we don't check for files nor directories anymore. So it is somewhat better, and somewhat worse. 

Thank you for taking so much time to help out anyway. That is quite helpful.

Comment: You are the man ! Thanks a ton sir, you really helped me out on this. That is very kind and appreciated. Could you explain to me very quickly what those two lines do : `RewriteRule ^(index\.)?[^.]*$ portail-index.php [L,NC]` and `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`. I don't really get them. 

Thank you again !

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means **do-nothing** if 2 `RewriteCond` meet above this line. So it means ignore all rules below for files and directories. Pattern `^(index\.)?[^.]*$` means match empty string (landing page) or `index.php` or `index.html` or anything that doesn't have a DOT

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton. What is the part of the regex that says `or anything that doesn't have a DOT` ? I see the `anything` bit, but not the `that doesn't have a DOT`.

Comment: `^[^.]*$` means anything but a DOT

Comment: I didn't know that a `^` in the beginning of a character set matched anything but those characters. You rock big time!